# With 2 group by columns, how can I do a subtotal by each of the group by columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

New to pandas. I'm trying to a subtotal within 2 group by columns. I have managed to figure out how to sum using 2 group by attributes but within that, I'm also trying to do a subtotal. Please see below for example -

```
df.groupby(['Fruit','Name'])['Number'].sum()
```

Output

```
Fruit   Name      Number   
Apples  Bob        16
        Mike        9
        Steve      10
                 ------
                   35
                 ------
Grapes  Bob        35
        Tom        87
        Tony       15
                 ------
                   137
                 ------
Oranges Bob        67
        Mike       57
        Tom        15
        Tony        1
```

What I'm looking for is to show a subtotal by each fruit within the dataframe. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mix of `unstack`, `assign`, and `stack` to do this:

```
sums = df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Name'])['Number'].sum().unstack().assign(Total=df.groupby('Fruit').sum()).stack()
```

Output:

```
>>> sums
Fruit    Name 
Apples   Bob       16.0
         Mike       9.0
         Steve     10.0
         Total     35.0
Grapes   Bob       35.0
         Tom       87.0
         Tony      15.0
         Total    137.0
Oranges  Bob       67.0
         Mike      57.0
         Tom       15.0
         Tony       1.0
         Total    140.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, can I apply this directly to the attribute ['Fruit'] if I wanted to get a subtotal for all the fruits?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean - will you please clarify a bit?

Comment: Sure, so say I wanted to get a subtotal for all the fruits within my dataframe, like subtotal for apples, and then grapes and then oranges. Can I still use this method?

Comment: If you do a `groupby`, and specific the first column to be `Fruits`, then yes.

Comment: Oh, do you mean get the subtotal for each fruit, without the person name, e.g. `df.groupby(['Fruit']).sum()`?

Comment: Exactly, so it would be just like my output above, except after each fruit there would be a subtotal under the number column.

Comment: Oh I see, I totally misunderstood the question; you want to get 35 (16+9+10) for Apples?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. So the row after apple ends would show subtotal 35, and so on for other fruits.

Comment: My apologies - I'm extra tired this evening I guess...haha

Comment: @Noobie in the future, it will help to provide some sample expected output to your question. It will aid answerers in getting the right answer. :)

Comment: Do you want the subtotal for each fruit _in addition_ to the subtotal for each person?

Comment: Sorry about that, I understood and tried to edit my question after you pointed out. Yes, Im looking for the subtotal by each of the two group by columns. In this case, fruit and name both.

Comment: Ah! I see the light finally! I'll see what I can do. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240117/discussion-between-noobie-and-user17242583).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `df.sum` or `df.groupby.sum` with `level=0`:

```
df.sum(level=0) # Will be deprecated
# or
df.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
Fruit
Apples      35
Grapes     137
Oranges    140
Name: Number, dtype: int64
```